# how separate the mouse click event and the courser click event in Aframe

Tags: aframe

I'm creating a VR Editor using AFRAME...
I need to create an event when the user clicks on an element by mouse and to do deferent action when clicking by Aframe camera cursor.

I found the `<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">` but this would do the same click event on both mouse and cursor click.
 is that possible in AFRAME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discriminate by the cursor element:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('on-click', {
    init: function () {
      var self = this;
      this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        if (self.el.sceneEl === evt.detail.cursorEl) {
          console.log("MOUSE");
        } else {
          console.log("CURSOR");
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Example: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/winter-sagittarius