# aframe switching between mouse and entity controls

Tags: aframe

I'm having massive problems getting mouse to work after the player has been in VR.

Updating the cursor attributes didn't do anything, so I've tried removing and replacing them

```
  getRayCasterAttributes: function(){

    return this.data.isVR ? 
      {
        cursorAttributes:{
          fuse: true,
          fuseTimeout: cursorFuseTimeout,
        },
        raycasterAttributes: {
          objects: '[data-raycastable]',
        },

      } :  
      {cursorAttributes:{
        fuse: true,
        fuseTimeout: cursorFuseTimeout,
        rayOrigin:  'mouse',
      },
      raycasterAttributes: {
        objects: '[data-raycastable]',
      },
      }
  }


 if(oldData.isVR !== this.data.isVR){
      this._recticle.object3D.visible = this.data.isVR
      this._recticle.removeAttribute('raycaster')
      this._recticle.removeAttribute('cursor')
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this.getRayCasterAttributes().raycasterAttributes, this.getRayCasterAttributes().cursorAttributes)
        this._recticle.setAttribute('raycaster', this.getRayCasterAttributes().raycasterAttributes)
        this._recticle.setAttribute('cursor', this.getRayCasterAttributes().cursorAttributes)
      },100)
```

This kind of works switching from 2D to VR with the timeout, but switching back is another major pain.

What is the best way to do this in aframe?

I've tried this, isn't helping. Works with mouse, does not switch to cursor controls when entering VR.

```
  this._recticle.setAttribute('cursor', {fuse: false, rayOrigin: 'mouse'})
else
  this._recticle.setAttribute('cursor', {fuse: true,rayOrigin: 'entity', fuseTimeout: 2000})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite would be `rayOrigin: entity`.

Comment: Thanks @ngokevin, this doesn't enable the gaze cursor. How do I do that after Mouse cursor has been enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Have a seperate cursor on the scene and in the camera, then you can have both

[how separate the mouse click event and the courser click event in Aframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56321191/how-separate-the-mouse-click-event-and-the-courser-click-event-in-aframe)

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/winter-sagittarius